In nuget manager show only top level packages when updating
I just updated to vs2022 17.12.0 and I just noticed that when updating nuget packages there is a new column for the Package level. Is there a way to disable this and show only the top-level packages when updating?
I have a solution in .NET 6 and because the nuget manager show new versions of a package even when my current framework is not supported (showing me a new version of Microsoft.Extensions.Http 9.0.0 when I can't use it in NET 6) I have to manually select a package and see if there is a new version for .NET 6 and update to that version.
But with this new version now is more confusing because selecting Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder it says that I have multiple versions installed, that freak me out at the beginning but after searching the different version came from a transitive package that I have no control of, but the top-level packages all have the same version.
Thanks

What I don't understand is that it selects all the projects including transitive to update them to an updated version of the package. I don't want to update all those projects. I only want to update the top-level projects.

@LockTar that's a mayor problem, I had to undo my changes to do it more carefully because I noticed csprojs with new packages when I all was doing is update versions

it is incredibly tedious to uncheck all then check only top level installed projects for each update. I don't understand if I'm missing something obvious or if there is really no better solution.
